# How to substitute the values of lat and lon inside https function into wURL(a constant)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-development-server

I was trying to make this weather web app using express.js and node.js, when i was struck with a problem. I want to use 'lat' and 'lon' values generated in https function into wURL(where i stored the url to get my weather data. This url only accepts latitude and longitude). So, can anyone help me find a solution for this.?

Thanks in advance.

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('node:https');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(\__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
const query = req.body.cityName;
const apiKey = "904f8e391a422fdf63b802aef88950c8";
const units = "metric";
//for lat long
const gURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + query + "&limit=2&appid=" + apiKey;
//for weather
const wURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + units;

https.get(gURL, function(response) {
response.on('data', function(data) {
const city = JSON.parse(data);
const lat = city\[0\].lat;
const lon = city\[0\].lon;
});
});

https.get(wURL, function(response) {
response.on('data', function(data) {
const climate = JSON.parse(data);
const temp = climate.main.temp;
const location = climate.name;
const description = climate.weather\[0\].description;
const icon = climate.weather\[0\].icon;
const imgURL = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/' + icon + '@2x.png';
res.write('\<h1\>The temperature in ' + location + ' is ' + temp + ' degC.\</h1\>');
res.write('\<p\>The weather is currently ' + description + '\</p\>');
res.write("\<img src=" + imgURL + "\>");
res.send();
})
})
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Server is running on port:3000");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- You define `wURL` too early, before `lat` and `lon` are known.
- `response.on('data', ...)` processes only the first chunk of an HTTP response. If the response is big, there may be more than one. Concatenate them all and process the concatenation in `response.on('end', ...)`.
- You can make the request to `wURL` only after you have processed the response from the `gURL` request completely.

```js
https.get(gURL, function(response) {
  var allData = "";
  response.on('data', function(data) {
    allData += data.toString();
  }).on('end', function() {
    const city = JSON.parse(allData);
    const lat = city[0].lat;
    const lon = city[0].lon;
    const wURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat +
      "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + units;
    https.get(wURL, function(response) {
      var allData = "";
      response.on('data', function(data) {
        allData += data.toString();
      }).on('end', function() {
        const climate = JSON.parse(allData);
        ...
        res.send();
      });
    });
  });
});
```